# 403 error server-status of docker container while accessing outside container

Tags: apache, docker

I am running apache server inside a docker container and exposed to my port 80:80 and when I hit 127.0.0.1:80 in my browser it shows it works but when I hit 127.0.0.1:80/server-status it shows ***403***  forbidden but when I access container and execute `curl container-IP:80/server-status` inside the container it shows output

Comment: What do the Apache logs tell you when you try to access the server status page from your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are missing in configuration, we don't have your apache config info but you can verify your config with this reference link [enable apache-status](https://techjourney.net/403-forbidden-error-when-enabling-server-status-in-apache-httpd-server/)

Comment: Yes the above worked fine but  need to make changes  inside conf file if you use apache 2.4 version follow this link [conf file changes for 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)